# I am using django for a project and i got this error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am doing a project in Django and i got this error.How is this occurs?
**NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'create_order' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_order/(?P[^/]+)/$']**

**urls.py**

from django.urls import path

from accounts import views

urlpatterns = [

```
path('',views.home, name="home"),
path('product/',views.products, name="product"),
path('customer/<str:pkid>/',views.customer, name="customer"),

path('create_order/<str:pk>/',views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
path('update_order/<str:pk>/',views.updateOrder, name="update_order"),
path('delete_order/<str:pk>/',views.deleteOrder, name="delete_order"),
```

]

**views.py**

def createOrder(request, pk):

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
form = OrderForm(initial={'customer':customer})
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid:
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
context =  {'form':form}
return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)
```

**order_form.html**

{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

```
<form action="" method="POST">


    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}

    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

{% endblock %}

**customer.html`**

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>Customer:{{customer.name}}</h5>
            <hr>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm btn-block">Update Customer</a>
            <a href="{% url 'create_order' customer.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm btn-block">Place Order</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>Contact Information</h5>
            <hr>
            <p>Email: {{customer.email}}</p>
            <p>Phone: {{customer.phone}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>Total Orders</h5>
            <hr>
            <h1 style="text-align:center;padding:10px">{{total_orders}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form method="get">
                
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Date Ordered</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
                {% for order in orders %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{order.product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.product.category}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.date_created}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.status}}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{% url 'update_order' order.id %}">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_order' order.id %}">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                
                {% endfor %}
            
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please make your code more readable

Comment: show the template the view createOrder is called from.

Answer (score 0):

The `NoReverseMatch` error is saying that Django cannot find a matching url pattern for the url you've provided in any of your installed app's urls.

In your HTML write `action=" {%url 'create_order' order.id%}"`